# CSS calc as percentage in safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

**TL;DR**

If I calculate height css property with `calc` using percentages safari doesn't seem to work as expected. Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/z0Lshem3/7/) for reference (Please open it in chrome, ff and safari)

References already checked:

- SO question(s) asked before: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443343/css-calc-not-working-in-safari-and-fallback), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958413/getting-percentages-to-work-in-css-calc-for-firefox-and-safari)
- Caniuse link for browser support [Link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). caniuse mentions that safari 10 supports calc.

The above questions seem to have been answered like 3 years ago. Has something changed with respect to css `calc` for safari?

**Environment:**

```
Macbook Pro,
Chrome -  54.0.2840.71
Safari -  10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7)
Firefox - 47.0.1
```

Not sure what I am missing in this. The above js fiddle link renders the same in FF and chrome but safari seems to ignore the height so the content overflows without proper scroll bar. Am I missing something here? Safari's implementation of `calc` doesn't support property calculations in percentage?